# Reduce gives wrong solutions

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

Given the follwing system of equations

```
eqs = {
  x/(x - 2) - 4/y == 1,
  x/(2 + 1/y) == y/(3 - 1/x)
  }
```

Although the domain of this system does not contain points (x,y) with x == 0, Reduce claimes (0,-4) to be a solution of the system

```
Reduce[eqs, {x, y}]
(x == 0 && y == -4) || (x == 6 && y == 8)

Reduce[eqs, {x, y}, Reals]
(x == 0 || x == 6) && y == -4 + 2 x
```

One gets this wrong solution also by hand when simplifying the two equations to

```
-4x-2y==-2
-3x+2y==-2
```

and using the accumulation method to solve the system.

I always expected Reduce to give correct results. Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Mathematica does automatic simplification in some cases which can change the domain of a function.  In your case

```
Simplify[eqs]
```

Gives {1/(2-x)+2/y==0, x y (1/(1-3 x)+1/(2 y+1))==0}, putting x=0 in the domain.  A similar thing happens with expressions like

```
Simplify[(x^2-36)/(x+6)]
```

Comment: I wonder how this ties in with the documentation, which says "The result of Reduce[expr,vars] always describes exactly the same mathematical set as expr. ".

Comment: That's exactly the point! I don't mind if Solve gives me some false solutions, since Solve treats the generic case. In contrast I expect Reduce not to change the set of solutions i.e. to handle all possible cases in the specified domain.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is similar to `Solve` returning "generic" solutions as in

```
Solve[a x == b, x]
```

> {{x -> b/a}}

which, of course, does not make sense for `a=0`. However, as the expression provided to `Solve` does not involve any other constraints, MMA gives the "generic" solution, i.e., one that holds for almost all values of `a`, `b`, except for (possibly) some values with zero Lebesgue measure (in this case, `a=0`).

Apparently, `Reduce` (or, maybe, `Simplify` if called internally) treats `x` the same way and provides solutions assuming that the input equations correspond to a "generic" `x`.

Of course, one could always provide explicit domain constraints:

```
Reduce[And @@ Flatten[{eqs, x != 0}], {x, y}]
```

> x == 6 && y == 8

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is consistent, sort of. 1/0 is ComplexInfinity in Mathematica, and 1/ComplexInfinity is 0, so it works. For an excellent analysis of both the pragmatic reasons for this, and the associated difficulties, see: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00125.html

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Mathematica.SE! This is an interesting point and link, but as it stands, your answer is more a comment than a full answer. Could you please expand on it a little, say, by summarising the content in the linked post?

Comment: Expand by summarizing? It really all comes down to whether you want to treat infinity as some sort of number. In applied math, we often do: we reason about perfectly stiff structural members or amplifiers with infinite bandwidth. Maybe we represent an infinite quantity by a zero reciprocal. Perhaps the equations above represent such a situation.

Comment: Mathematica's design is essentially pragmatic here: it uses "compactification" heuristically, as when it reduces x/x to 1. It does a good job of reproducing the way we do applied math, but it's not full consistent as Andrzej points out in the link.

Comment: If I apply `eqs/.x->0` Mathematica produces the warning Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered." before returning the result `{-(4/y) == 1, True}`. This way I can check the results Reduce returns: With `res = Reduce[eqs, {x, y}]`, `eqs /. ToRules[res[[1]]]` returns `{True, True}` with the warning mentioned above.

Comment: Does anyone know how to restrict the domain to the open Reals or Complex set, i.e. to avoid any compactification?