# Why does Reduce[x + 1/x == 1/x, x] give the result x == 0, instead of the result False?

Tags: equation-solving

Why does

```
Reduce[x + 1/x == 1/x, x]
```

give the result

```
x == 0
```

instead of the result False? There is no value of x that causes Mathematica to return True when substituted into x + 1/x == 1/x. If Mathematica can never make the equation True, then why doesn't Reduce return the value False?

I have looked at a couple of related questions (such as [Reduce gives wrong solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80567/reduce-gives-wrong-solutions)), but all the related questions that I saw involved parameters or two or more variables. This equation doesn't raise all the same issues those examples did. Many thanks for any answers!

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation by x and you get: x^2+1==1, which does indeed have x->0 as a solution. Maybe this is what the program is "thinking". Note that Solve[x^2 + 1 == 1, x] gives the same answer, but SolveAlways[x^2 + 1 == 1, x] returns the empty set.

Comment: In fact, it shouldn't yield `x == 0` however this is satisfactory: `Reduce[x + 1/x == 1/x && FunctionDomain[ x + 1/x, x], x]`

Comment: If somehow the transformation `A == B` to `A - B == 0` is made, then all is lost, if the domains of `A` and `B` are ignored. Compare `Reduce[x + a/x == b/x && a == b, x]` (`False`) and `Reduce[x + a/x == a/x, x]` (`x == 0`).

Comment: @bills Note that the second argument to `SolveAlways` are the variables you do not want to solve for (e.g. `SolveAlways[x == 0, x]` returns the empty set). The equivalent call to the OP's example is `SolveAlways[x + 1/x == 1/x, {}]`, which returns `{{x -> 0}}`.

Comment: @Michael E2 -- thanks for that. SolveAlways has always been confusing to me!

Comment: @Artes That's a nice command to know - I'm using version 9 but look forward to trying FunctionDomain when I upgrade next.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Inspired by your example I checked Reduce[x + a/x == b/x, x] and found the satisfactory result (x == Sqrt[b-a] || x == -Sqrt[b-a])&&(x != 0).