# Wrong domain of 1/x

Tags: equation-solving

I am experimenting with Reduce. I found a weird behavior. Consider this example:

```
Reduce[Element[1/(x + 1), Reals], x, Reals]
```

This should produce the domain of the function 1/(x+1). It gives the correct result in output:

```
 x < -1 || x > -1
```

But if I apply the same idea to a simpler example:

```
Reduce[Element[1/x, Reals], x, Reals]
```

The output is

```
True
```

which is wrong! The two examples are very similar, why does one work and not the other? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think it's a bug.  I'm pretty sure it happens because the domain spec (3rd arg. `Reals`) results in an assumption `Element[x, Reals]`.  Somehow then a mistake is made when analyzing `Power[x, -1]`, whose first argument is assumed to be in the reals, and not when analyzing `Power[x + 1, -1]`, whose first argument needs to be analyzed to determined whether it is real. It is in the analysis that the condition that the denominator must be nonzero is developed, which analysis is skipped in the `1/x` case.  Note `Reduce[Element[1/(x + 0.), Reals], x, Reals]` gives the correct result, too.

Comment: Thank you for this remark. Note that ```Reduce[Element[1/(CubeRoot[x])^2, Reals], x, Reals]``` and ```Reduce[Element[1/x^2, Reals], x, Reals]``` still give the wrong result. Instead, the very similar ```Reduce[Element[1/CubeRoot[x^2], Reals], x, Reals]``` gives the correct result. Very puzzling. It really seems a bug.

Comment: I have found this other thread, without answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155895/why-does-reducex-1-x-1-x-x-give-the-result-x-0-instead-of-the-result     Is it possible this is because of the same bug?

Comment: It seems unlikely to be the same bug.  `Reduce[x + 1 + 1/(x + 1) == 1/(x + 1), x]` returns `x == -1`.  Also the domain is not set `Reals`, and `Reduce[Element[1/x, Reals], x]` works fine.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you very much! Maybe this is the fix I need. I will now try to use ```Reduce[Reduce[Element[1/x, Reals], x], x, Reals]``` This seems to give the correct result in all my examples.

Comment: To add more examples to the bug,  consider the following: ```Reduce[Abs[1/(x + 1)] < Infinity, x, Reals]```  ```Reduce[Abs[1/(x + 1)] < Infinity, x]```  They both don't work, with or withour the Reals domain. But the following works correctly ```Reduce[Abs[1/Cos[x]] < Infinity, x, Reals]``` This time, if I remove the reals, it doesn't work any more  ```Reduce[Abs[1/Cos[x]] < Infinity, x]```

Comment: Actually, I experimented a bit more, and I see that Michael's suggestion is not always good enough for me. For example, to compute the domain of Sin[x] Cos[x] I can use ```Reduce[Element[Cos[x] + Sin[x] Cos[x], Reals], x , Reals] ```, which works, but the alternative ```Reduce[Reduce[Element[Sin[x] Cos[x], Reals], x ], x, Reals] ```  does not work any more.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to use `Reduce`, then you can use [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html), which gives the right answer in both cases.

```
FunctionDomain[{1/(x + 1), 1/(x + 1) ∈ Reals}, x, Reals]
FunctionDomain[{1/x, 1/x ∈ Reals}, x, Reals]
```

> x < -1 || x > -1
>
> x < 0 || x > 0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of FunctionDomain, but it does not work for what I need. Consider, for example, the tangent function, between 0 and 2 Pi. If I look for the domain with FunctionDomain ```FunctionDomain[{Tan[x], x > 0, x < 2 Pi}, x] ``` I get an answer which I don't manage to simplify to a union of intervals. If I compute the same domain with Reduce ```Reduce[Element[Tan[x], Reals] && x > 0 && x < 2 Pi, x , Reals]```, I get the answer I need.