# problem with solving inequality $x+1/x>-1+1/x$. different answer in Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I tried to solve inequality $x+1/x>-1+1/x$ with Wolfram Alpha, and it gave me the answer $(-1,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$. This is correct.

But when I try to solve it in Wolfram Mathematica 12.0 (with Wolframscript) it gives me an answer $(-1,+\infty)$ – with zero inside the answer – this is wrong.

I used this command in Wolframscript: `Reduce[x+1/x>-1+1/x,x,Reals]`.

What's wrong with my script command?

Comment: I think this is more of a mathematical question than a Mathematica question. In some sense you're right that $x=0$ shouldn't be considered a valid solution; on the other hand, if we just assume that $1/x$ is a symbol (even if it's infinite at $x=0$), then we can cancel it on both sides (since it's the same symbol). It's quite a matter of precise definitions to judge what's correct here.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211272/wrong-domain-of-1-x -- Consider telling Wolfram Support and reporting back here what they say.

Comment: Workaround: `Reduce[# && FunctionDomain[List @@ #, #2], #2, Reals] &[
 x + 1/x > -1 + 1/x, x]`

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1878991).

Comment: `Reduce` and even `Solve` seem to not check the domain of the conditions, so it seems for now always explicitly give the domain if there are punctures in your definition.